# Reinitialize recycled Bitmap Android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, recycle

What I'm trying to do is to reuse a Bitmap after recycling it. For doing that, I know that I have to initialize de Bitmap again, I'm doing it this way after calling recycle():

```
mapBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(map, 0, 0, map.getWidth(), map.getHeight());
```

but when I try to use it, i get

```
06-12 20:41:01.628 615-1470/com.example.project W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@5f1fba3
```

By the way, I have another Bitmap which I have to recycle and use later on, but this one works perfectly, the only difference between them is that I'm initiallizating this one using decodeFile() as follows:

```
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);
```

Comment: When you call `mapBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(map, 0, 0, map.getWidth(), map.getHeight());` You are using the `map` object which is a recycled Bitmap and thus the error

Comment: please post full code for review and detailed recommendations.

Comment: there is a simple answer: **you can't** reuse recycled bitmap, as there is nothing to reuse, since it is **recycled**, dead, errazed, removed, garbage-collected. It does not exist any more.

Comment: @MatPag you're right, it seems like when I call recycle on mapBitmap, map is also recycled so I have to reinstantiate both of them. Put your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @JOSEMAFUEN Done ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a recycled `Bitmap` to initialize another one.
In this line:

```
mapBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(map, 0, 0, map.getWidth(), map.getHeight());
```

you are using the `map` object which is a recyled Bitmap, and you can't create a new Bitmap using a recycled one, be sure to initialize it properly before calling `Bitmap.createBitmap(map, ...)` or don't call `map.recycle()` somewhere in your code before you have finished using it.